# Select 2nd column of stored procedure's output

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, linq

My stored procedure returns this

```
1 skl meter 50
```

I want my c# program to select the skl from the output.

I am currently doing this

```
SqlDataReader dr=comm.ExecuteReader();
var fal = dr.Read();

if (fal)
{
   var skl = dr.GetString(1);
}
```

and it doesn't work.

How would I select Skl or any other value from a sql output?

The problem is it selects skl even if skl isn't present in the output

Comment: **HOW** does it *not work*?? Do you get an error - if so: **what is that error**?

Comment: Can you clarify whether that output is appearing as text, or is it in a result set? If it's in a result set, you'd be better selecting the column by name rather than ordinal.

Comment: Can you show your storedprocedure text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Procedure Returns more than 1 row of data, then I would suggest binding to a Datagrid.
This way you can also view the output and is a (ui) way of debugging.
Once you have the datagrid view showing your rows of data I would then do something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells["Name of the field"].Value != DBNull.Value)
    {
        string Myval = row.Cells["Name of the field"].Value;
    }
}
```

But this is a long way of doing it and checking. To be Honest the method your using I think should work, Are you Receiving an error? or is the value wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for null and hasrows

```
         if(rdr.HasRows)
         {
                rdr.read();
                string strValue = string.Empty;
                if (!rdr.IsDBNull(1)) strValue = rdr.GetString(1);
          }
          else {} // woops
```